# how to stop getting replica heartbeat related logs in mongodb log file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-administration

I want to avoid getting MongoDB replication heartbeat logs in my mongod.log  file as it is causing large size of log file. I have already implemented the below things to control log size which are working also:-

1. db.getProfilingStatus()
   {
   "was" : 0,
   "slowms" : 100
   }
2. Automated Log Rotation 
   https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/rotate-log-files/

But, in addition to this I do not want continuous replica set heartbeat logs

**Example-**

2017-02-06T11:03:59.160+0530 I COMMAND  [conn418] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", configVersion: 2, from: "192.168.6.72:27018", fromId: 1, term: 263 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:405 locks:{} protocol:op_command 0ms
2017-02-06T11:03:59.515+0530 I COMMAND  [conn417] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", configVersion: 2, from: "192.168.6.72:27019", fromId: 2, term: 263 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:405 locks:{} protocol:op_command 0ms
2017-02-06T11:04:01.161+0530 I COMMAND  [conn418] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", configVersion: 2, from: "192.168.6.72:27018", fromId: 1, term: 263 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:405 locks:{} protocol:op_command 0ms

Please suggest a solution for the same.
Thanks..